# DateTime string issue

Tags: php, string, datetime

If I define `$ETA = strftime("'%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S'", $ETA_time)` instead of `$ETA = '2013-08-28 09:24:00'`, then the following code fails at line `$datetime_from = new DateTime($datetime_from_string)`:

```
$ETA = '2013-08-28 09:24:00';   
$datetime_from_string = $ETA;
$datetime_from = new DateTime($datetime_from_string);   
$datetime_till = new DateTime($datetime_from_string);
$datetime_till->modify('+45 minutes');
```

In one case `var_dump($ETA)` shows `2013-08-28 09:24:00`, in the other case - `'2013-08-28 09:24:00'` (in this case DateTime fails). How to fix it?

Comment: Error message is missing in your question. If there is no error message what does *"is failing"* means? What is expected? what did you get instead?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Single quotes inside are not needed.

Change

```
$ETA = strftime("'%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S'", $ETA_time)
```

to

```
$ETA = strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S", $ETA_time)
```